# Where Can I Find the Master Minimum Equipment List for the A320 Series (UK / EUR)?

Tags: easa-regulations, equipment, airbus-a320

I'm currently trying to locate the Master Minimum equipment list for an Airbus 321.

I have the FAA (US) version of this document, but I'd like a copy of the UK or EUR version if possible.

---

The Master Minimum Equipment List page on CAA doesn't contain a link to the any airbus series

http://www.caa.co.uk/application.aspx?catid=33&pagetype=65&appid=11&mode=list&type=sercat&id=16

I found a page on the flight safety committee that contains 5 historical links to lists for the A320 series aircraft. But all of these links are dead.

http://www.ukfsc.co.uk/information/caa-notifications/275-caa-master-minimum-equipment-list-amendements-mmel

---

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I can find this document? I would prefer the revision that was current in September 2013 for UK and Europe.

Comment: Send an email to Airbus?

Comment: @ratchetfreak thanks... I've sent an email to CAA asking for this information, but in my experience they aren't very timely at responding..  I did check the Airbus website, but unless I'm missing something obvious, they don't have a contact email address on there. [Airbus Contact Page](http://www.airbus.com/tools/contacts)

Comment: The FAA has a list [here](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICResults.aspx?mode=Publication&doctype=MMEL) that includes Rev 22a, dated 2/7/2013 (Feb 7th).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest revision of the MMEL for the A320 family was approved a month ago by EASA. The [EASA website](https://easa.europa.eu/document-library/master-minimum-equipment-lists?search=airbus&date_filter%5Bmin%5D%5Bdate%5D=&date_filter%5Bmax%5D%5Bdate%5D=&field_easa_supplement_value=All) only contains a PDF document with the [MMEL approval signature](https://easa.europa.eu/document-library/master-minimum-equipment-lists/airbus-a318a319a320a321) for Airbus aircraft.  For some manufacturers (e.g. Cessna) the full MMEL is included on the EASA website.

The [information page](https://easa.europa.eu/master-minimum-equipment-lists-information) on MMELs says:

> Each MMEL document is the property of the (S)TC holder, and only made
>   available here in full if requested by the (S)TC holder. If a full
>   copy is not available here then please contact the (S)TC Holder to get
>   a copy of the document in question.

So you have to contact Airbus in this case.